# How to make a div font size subscribe to a value(firebase)?

Tags: html, css, angular, firebase, fonts

I have a div that I increase in font-size when I click a upvote button:

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'font-size': size + 'px'}" class="questions" *ngFor="let question of questions | async">
  <a class="counters">{{ question.data.upvotes }}</a>
  <br>
  <a (click)="size = size + 3; increment(question.id)" class="chevrons">&#9650;</a>
  <br>
  <a (click)="size = size - 3; decrement(question.id)" class="chevrons">&#9660;</a>
  <a class="question">{{ question.data.question }}</a>
</div>
```

Problem is, this changes the font-size locally. Let's say I have a firebase field `upvotes` that increments by one everytime I upvote - is there a way for the div to subscribe to that value, so that if for example I open two browsers and upvote in one browser, the div font size increases in both browsers?

Comment: You can make the font size follow value from firebase, but what i understood is you want real time update between browser right?

As i can see you need to use websocket to push notification from server to clients.

Help link https://tutorialedge.net/typescript/angular/angular-websockets-tutorial/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by subscribing the data;

```
this.questions = this.questionsCol.snapshotChanges()
  .map(actions => {
    return actions.map(a => {
      const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Questions;
      const id = a.payload.doc.id;
      return { id, data };
    })
  })
```

and adding it to my div's fontsize property using ngStyle:

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'font-size': question.data.upvotes + 12 + 'px'}" class="questions" *ngFor="let question of questions | async">
```